# MixItUP Multi Filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter

Im need your help, cause i'm looking for a solution to handle a multifilter in MixItUp.
So i use the Park example of the site, but my version didn't work :). So here is my code + a jsfiddle. Can someone figure out what i have done wrong?

So the filter is working, but only with one filter attribute. So if i try to select one attribute of the first filter it will be set to .active and when i choose one attribute of the second filter the .active switch to these attribute. -> http://jsfiddle.net/zm3j3/

I want to do it like here.  -> http://mixitup.io/demos/parks

```
<div id="Filters">
    <ul class="filter_leucht">
        <span class="title">Leuchtentype</span>
        <ul class="">
            <li class="filter" data-dimension="leuchtentype" data-filter="all">All</li>
            <li class="filter" data-dimension="leuchtentype" data-filter="leucht1">Leucht1</li>
            <li class="filter" data-dimension="leuchtentype" data-filter="leucht2">Leucht2</li>
         </ul>
    </ul>


    <ul class="filter_regionen">
        <span class="">Regionen</span>
        <ul class="title">
            <li class="filter" data-dimension="regionen" data-filter="all">All</li>
            <li class="filter" data-dimension="regionen" data-filter="region1">Region1</li>
            <li class="filter" data-dimension="regionen" data-filter="region2">Region2</li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
</div>

<ul id="Referenz" class="layout_list">

    <li class="mix region1 leucht1">
      <a href="#">
                <img src="http://img2.fotoalbum.virgilio.it/v/www1-3/176/176513/304872/IMG_0880-vi.jpg" alt="Projekt 1" title="Projekt 1">
      </a>
    </li>

    <li class="mix region1 leucht2">
      <a href="#">
      <img src="http://i.livescience.com/images/i/000/054/306/i02/beach-health.jpg?1372365869" alt="Projekt 2" title="Projekt 2">
          </a>
    </li>

    <li class="mix region2 leucht2">
      <a href="#">
                <img src="http://img2.fotoalbum.virgilio.it/v/www1-3/176/176513/304872/IMG_0880-vi.jpg" alt="Projekt 1" title="Projekt 1">
      </a>
    </li>

    <li class="mix region2 leucht2">
      <a href="#">
      <img src="http://i.livescience.com/images/i/000/054/306/i02/beach-health.jpg?1372365869" alt="Projekt 2" title="Projekt 2">
          </a>
    </li>

</ul>
```

And my JS

```
    $(function(){

        // INSTANTIATE MIXITUP

        $('#Referenz').mixitup({    
            effects: ['fade','blur'], // List of effects 
        });

        // Bind checkbox click handlers:

        $filters.on('click',function(){
            var $t = $(this),
                dimension = $t.attr('data-dimension'),
                filter = $t.attr('data-filter'),
                filterString = dimensions[dimension];

            if(filter == 'all'){
                // If "all"
                if(!$t.hasClass('active')){
                    // if unchecked, check "all" and uncheck all other active filters
                    $t.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
                    // Replace entire string with "all"
                    filterString = 'all';   
                } else {
                    // Uncheck
                    $t.removeClass('active');
                    // Emtpy string
                    filterString = '';
                }
            } else {
                // Else, uncheck "all"
                $t.siblings('[data-filter="all"]').removeClass('active');
                // Remove "all" from string
                filterString = filterString.replace('all','');
                if(!$t.hasClass('active')){
                    // Check checkbox
                    $t.addClass('active');
                    // Append filter to string
                    filterString = filterString == '' ? filter : filterString+' '+filter;
                } else {
                    // Uncheck
                    $t.removeClass('active');
                    // Remove filter and preceeding space from string with RegEx
                    var re = new RegExp('(\\s|^)'+filter);
                    filterString = filterString.replace(re,'');
                };
            };

            // Set demension with filterString
            dimensions[dimension] = filterString;

            // We now have two strings containing the filter arguments for each dimension:  
            console.info('dimension 1: '+dimensions.regionen);
            console.info('dimension 2: '+dimensions.leuchtentype);


            $('#Referenz').mixitup('filter',[dimensions.regionen, dimensions.leuchtentype])         

        });

    });
```

Best regards

Comment: Please define "my version didn't work"

Comment: `$filters` was undefined. Try this http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/zm3j3/1/

Comment: Oky i defined it. But Multi select is not working. For better understanding what i'm trying to get is this -> http://mixitup.io/demos/parks So in my example that when you select an attribute in the first filter and then one in the second, than only the object, with both attributes, should be visible.